# Task doesn't change parameters

Tags: c#, multithreading, winforms, closures, task-parallel-library

I am playing with Task functions and found a pretty strange problem that I run Task in for loop and pass the parameters to function (i) the loop count is 100.
As I expected the output would be like this.
1
2
3
4
5
But the output I get from this function is
100
100
100
I mean it won't change to new parameters. For more details I uploaded the whole project.

[Download Sample Program that I made!](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/1357496/WindowsFormsApplication2.zip)

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace WindowsFormsApplication2
{
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        CheckForIllegalCrossThreadCalls = false;
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Task.Factory.StartNew(() => button_tast());
    }
    void button_tast()
    {
        Task[] tk =new Task[100];
        for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
        {
            tk[i] = Task.Factory.StartNew(() => taskThread(i));
        }
        Task.WaitAll(tk);
    }
void taskThread(int i){
    listBox1.Items.Add(i);
}
}
}
```

Comment: Please post the relevant code here.

Comment: Eric Lippert's [Closing over Loop variables considered harmful](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2009/11/12/closing-over-the-loop-variable-considered-harmful.aspx)

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever That article is with respect to `foreach`, it's not really about `for`, for which it's clear that the scope of the variable ought to be outside the loop.

Comment: @Servy - it discusses what closing over a loop variable *means*, using **foreach**. It also, right at the top, tells you that the **foreach** behaviour changes for c# 5, but that **for** isn't changed. I thought it was a useful enough signpost.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It's because you're [closing over the loop variable](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2009/11/12/closing-over-the-loop-variable-considered-harmful.aspx). You can rewrite the loop as

```
for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
{
    int taskNumber = i
    tk[i] = Task.Factory.StartNew(() => taskThread(taskNumber));
}
```

and you'll be fine

Comment: If he hadn't access `listBox1` in Tasks.

Comment: Wow, Thanks man its working + I gain pretty nice knowledge thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that from the point of view of the Tasks, the variable `i` is global, and can be modified in a non-threadsafe manner.  This is easily rectified though....

```
        for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
        {
            int localCopy = i;
            tk[i] = Task.Factory.StartNew(() => taskThread(localCopy));
        }
```